# Hibernate criteria by latitude and longitude

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, latitude-longitude

Having a MySQL table with more than 20 millions of rows, there is some way with Hibernate to build a criteria in order to get nearest rows given a latitude and longitude?

Using `Criteria` would be great because I need to use more filters (price, category, etc).

Finally, it's posible get the rows ordered by distance? Or there are too much rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plan A** With a large number of rows,
`INDEX(lat)` is a non-starter, performance-wise,
even with restricting to a stripe:
`AND lat BETWEEN 65 AND 69`.
`INDEX(lat, lng)` is no better because the optimizer would
not use both columns, even with `AND lng BETWEEN...`

**Plan B** Your next choice will involve lat and lng, plus a subquery.
And version 5.6 would be beneficial. It's something like
this (after including `INDEX(lat, lng, id)`):

```
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT id FROM tbl
        WHERE lat BETWEEN... 
          AND lng BETWEEN... ) x
    JOIN tbl USING (id)
    WHERE ...;
```

For various reasons, Plan B is only slightly better than Plan A.

**Plan C** With millions of rows, you will need
[my pizza parlor algorithm](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).
This involves a Stored Procedure to repeatedly probe
the table, looking for enough rows.
It also involves PARTITIONing to get a crude 2D index.
The link has reference code that includes filtering on things like category.

Plans A and B are O(sqrt(N)); Plan C is O(1).
That is, for Plans A and B, if you quadruple the number of rows,
you double the time taken. Plan C does not get
slower as you increase N.